# Unsure How to Take This Fourier Transform's Inverse?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have to convolve the following signal and its impulse response, and I thought taking the Fourier Transform would be the best approach:

$$x(t) = te^{-2t}*u(t)$$

$$ h(t) = e^{-4t}*u(t)$$

Where $u(t)$ is the unit step/Heaviside function.

I know that convolution in the time domain is equivalent to a multiplication in the frequency domain, I performed the following conversions from a table intending to multiply:

$$X(w) = \frac{1}{(2 + jw)^2}$$

$$ H(w) = \frac{1}{(4 + jw)} $$

I got a little stuck here. When I multiply out, I'm not sure how to simply into something I can read off a table for an inverse transform, if at all, to get the time domain convolution.

Can anyone offer any assistance? Greatly appreciated! My apologies for my lack of LaTEX ability.

**EDIT** My solution attempt with partial fractions (and having a go at LaTEX as well!) Can anyone confirm?

$$Y(w) = \frac{1}{4(4 + jw)} - \frac{1}{(4(2 + jw)} + \frac{1} {2(2 + jw)^2}$$

Comment: Multiply through (don't expand the denominator) and do a partial fractions decomposition.

Comment: OK, it wasn't straightforward due to the squared term as expected, but my result was Y(w) = 1/4(4 + jw) - 1/(4(2 + jw) + 1/ 2(2 + jw)^2. That certainly seems reasonable to me!

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{(2+j\omega)^2(4+j\omega)}=\frac{1/j^3}{1/j^3(2+j\omega)^2(4+j\omega)}=\frac{j}{(\omega-j2)^2(\omega-4j)}$$

Now use partial fraction decomposition.